# Remove anchor underline email signature

Tags: html, email, gmail, signature, hotmail

I am developing custom email signatures for a client of mine, I am now at testing stage for GMail, Hotmail, Brinkster and so on.

I'm having a hard time trying to remove the underline the anchor is displaying, I do have " text-decoration: none;" on the anchor itself and nothing is working for either client however, Outlook renders fine.

Can anyone help? :-)

Answer (score 7):

I think your issue may be that certain clients move anchor styles and text into a span and apply the style definitions to that instead.

```
<a href="/" style="color:black;">hello, world!</a>
```

becomes

```
<a href="/"><span style="color:black;">hello, world!</span></a>
```

Not 100% sure why they do this, but it's annoying. Sometimes changing to something like this works:

```
<a href="/" style="color:black;" href="/"><span style="color:black;">hello, world!</span></a>
```

But it's still a mixed bag and changing all the time. Unfortunately the only way to confirm that things always look right is to use an image.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try adding `!important` to the style:

```
text-decoration: none !important;
```

Comment: After some more googling, it looks like many people have the same issue. Styling in email is a pain. This site has promise for bringing standards to email clients (but who knows how long that will take!) http://www.email-standards.org/ Sorry I wasn't more helpful! :)

Comment: Haha yeah creating html signatures is a pain to render in all clients but thanks for the info buddy! :-)

Comment: I was inserting a link in my signature in Mozilla Thunderbird and your solution was just what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <a href="example.com" style="text-decoration:none">link text</a>
```

won't have an underline unless there is a higher priority css rule somewhere else.

Comment: I have this already and no fix, I have removed the default Microsoft Signature styling for links etc and still not working